# Align sup tag within centered flexbox

Tags: flexbox

I'm struggeling to align the sup tag in the right position within a centered flexbox

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  
  sup {
    color: red;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, nam reprehenderit eum assumenda illo voluptatibus fugit reiciendis impedit omnis provident dolorum quae itaque quaerat perferendis est? Exercitationem, quas. Blanditiis, dignissimos.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, nam reprehenderit eum assumenda illo voluptatibus fugit reiciendis impedit omnis provident dolorum quae itaque quaerat perferendis est? Exercitationem, quas. Blanditiis, dignissimos.<sup>3</sup>
</div>
  </div>
```

Here is my code on codepen:
https://codepen.io/Bizboss/pen/eYBNGVR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<sup>`need to be in a `<p>` tag

```css
.card {

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
   
 
}
 sup {
    color: red;
 

    
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, nam reprehenderit eum assumenda illo voluptatibus fugit reiciendis impedit omnis provident dolorum quae itaque quaerat perferendis est? Exercitationem, quas. Blanditiis, dignissimos.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, nam reprehenderit eum assumenda illo voluptatibus fugit reiciendis impedit omnis provident dolorum quae itaque quaerat perferendis est? Exercitationem, quas. Blanditiis, dignissimos.<sup>3</sup></p>
</div>
  </div>
```